# How can i change a color of button thats inside a map function without changing all the buttons color in react?

Tags: reactjs, react-hooks

[here is the image of my code](https://i.stack.imgur.com/JKMjG.png)I'm building a Twitter like app and i'm trying to build the 'Like' menu at the bottom of every tweet.
at the moment the 'Like' is a button and i want to change it's color once pressed.
the obvious problem is that all the other tweets 'likes' buttons are changing too..
i've tried everything i can using useState hooks and nothing worked..
any ideas?

Comment: please provide your code, what have you done so far?

Comment: I'm new here and cant understand how to attach the code without an image..

Comment: Just copy, paste will work fine. You can put your code inside  " ``` /* code here */ ``` " and it will format as a code

Answer (score 0, accepted):

What I would do is, I would store the `liked` info inside the item. So when you add like, you can change `item.liked = true` or `item.liked = false`

And once you do that you can style based on the item's liked field:

```
<button style={{backgroundColor: item.liked ? 'red' : ''}} ...
```